# Upgrade Xorg drivers breaks multiple display monitor Nvidia card Quadro610M [Ubuntu14.04]?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors

I recently upgraded the xserver drivers `xserver-xorg-core` and `xserver-common` to their latest versions (1.15.1-0ubuntu2.6). Ever since I am unable to correctly get a dual monitor setup working. Before everything was working just fine.

I use a Nvidia Quadro610M (HP ZBook15) running the latest Nvidia drivers (340).

As soon as I try to extend the display on two monitors using the "System Settings" in Unity, gives me unwanted behaviour (wrong dimensions, resolution, alignment, unable to point and click in second screen, etc. ...). This happens for many combinations of settings for resolution and display position. The only thing that seems to work is using only a single display: thus displaying either only on the built-in laptop display or only the external plugged 22" monitor (DVI connected)

Using the nvidia software (`nvidia-settings`) also doesn't help. For some reason beyond my understanding the Nvidia tool doesn't even detect the built-in laptop display in the GUI.

Note that all of the above posed no problem whatsoever before upgrading the xserver drivers.

Any ideas ?

UPDATE: /etc/X11/xorg.conf

> Section "ServerLayout"
>       Identifier "layout"
>       Screen 0 "nvidia"
>       Inactive "intel" EndSection
>
> Section "Device"
>       Identifier "intel"
>       Driver "intel"
>       BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
>       Option "AccelMethod" "SNA" EndSection
>
> Section "Screen"
>       Identifier "intel"
>       Device "intel" EndSection
>
> Section "Device"
>       Identifier "nvidia"
>       Driver "nvidia"
>       BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
>       Option "ConstrainCursor" "off" EndSection
>
> Section "Screen"
>       Identifier "nvidia"
>       Device "nvidia"
>       Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
>       Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT" EndSection

Comment: identical problem going on here. Dell M3800 with Quadro 1100M. nvidia settings sees one huge 5120x1800 monitor even though the actual situation is built in 3200*1800 and external (displayport) is full HD (1920x1080). So clearly it's adding the vertical res of the two screens but cutting off big parts of the external full HD because that doesn't ahve the same horizontal resolution. No way to be able to force this. Anything I need to do? Manually edit xorg.conf? To put what there? 
Nouveau works fine but then I can't use CUDA. Very frustrating. Anybody have any help here? Cant uncommon.